# Пулл-реквест и добавление ревьювера

Tags: github, pull-request

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в гитхабе на свой проект открыть пулл реквест и добавить ревьювера,что бы он мог смотреть мой проект? спасибо.

Comment: Вы уже почитали справку гитхаба?

Comment: конечно. но я не совсем понимаю: что бы мне добавить ревьевера , мне нужно его сначала добавить как коллаборатора?